# Задача: "Знал бы прикуп...". Яндекс.Контест

Tags: python, алгоритм

каким способом можно решить подобную задачу? Написал своё решение, но больно уж оно огромное и не проходит дальше 5-го теста. Понимаю, что тут скорее всего есть какой-то алгоритм, но не могу к нему подойти.
[image: Описание задачи]

[image: Примеры ввода и вывода]

[image: Описание примеров]

Comment: Обыно такое решается через динамическре программирование, пример https://leetcode.com/problems/best-time-to-buy-and-sell-stock-iv/

Answer (score 1):

Пройдите по массиву с конца, поддерживая текущий максимум (индекс `imax`) от `k+1`-го элемента до конца массива, и вычисляя наилучшую разность `p[imax]-p[k]`, обновляйте максимум текущей выгоды, и записывайте эти значения во вспомогательный массив `V`. Таким образом, `V[k]` будет описывать лучшее вложение начиная с `k`-го элемента до конца.

Теперь пройдите от начала, поддерживая текущий минимум (индекс `imin`) от начала массива до `j-1` элемента, вычисляя наилучшую разность `p[j]-p[imin]` c учётом вложения одного рубля, поддерживая максимум лучшего вложения `Best` от начала до `k`-го элемента, и комбинируйте текущий максимум с `V[k+1]`, запоминайте лучшее значение  `Best*V[k+1]`

Алгоритм линейный