# Вычислить оптимальные по доходу дни для сделок по покупке акций (Python)

Tags: python, алгоритм

Помогите, пожалуйста, понять алгоритм написания кода, который бы искал не более 4 пар сделок купли продажи таким образом, чтобы получилась максимальная выгода. Никак не мог понять, как расписать алгоритм. Максимум, до чего додумался - это нарезать список цен в разные дни на подсписки так, чтобы начало следующего подспика был меньше конца предыдущего, то есть разбить на последовтельные подсписки. Вот условие и мой код

[image: Условие]

[image: Формат ввода и вывода]

[image: данные для теста]

[image: Примечания]

```
N = int(input())
prices = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
dprices = dict(zip(range(1, N + 1), prices))
a = []
s = []
i = prices.index(min(prices))
while i != len(prices) - 1:
    s.append(prices[i])
    if prices[i] > prices[i+1] or i == len(prices)-2:
        a.append(s)
        s = []
    i += 1
a[-1].append(prices[-1])
print(a)
day1 = []
day2 = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    for key, value in dprices.items():
        if a[i][0] == value:
            day1.append(key)
        if a[i][-1] == value:
            day2.append(key)

days = tuple(zip(day1, day2))
print(len(days))
for item in days:
    print(*item)
```

Comment: В чём состоит вопрос?

Comment: [Было](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1494073/)

Comment: Вопрос в том, правилен ли ход моих мыслей и есть какой-то другой алгоритм, до которого я не додумался. То, что было представлено MBo, я не совсем понял и полагаю, что подходит не для всех условий

Comment: Неправилен, например, он выдаёт что попало для '1 4 3 2 3 5'

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Задача: "Знал бы прикуп...". Яндекс.Контест](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1494073/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0-%d0%97%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%bf-%d0%af%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81-%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82)

Comment: @Liparit G_A Если не разобрались, задавайте вопросы

Comment: вот сейчас думаю, как сформулировать вопрос

Answer (score 2):

Реализуем то, что я написал в [дубликате](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1494620/291659)

> Пройдите по массиву с конца, поддерживая текущий максимум (индекс
> `imax`) от `k+1`-го элемента до конца массива, и вычисляя наилучшую
> разность `p[imax]-p[k]`, обновляйте максимум текущей выгоды, и
> записывайте эти значения во вспомогательный массив `V`. Таким образом,
> `V[k]` будет описывать лучшее вложение начиная с `k`-го элемента до конца.
>
> Теперь пройдите от начала, поддерживая текущий минимум (индекс `imin`)
> от начала массива до `j-1` элемента, вычисляя наилучшую разность
> `p[j]-p[imin]` c учётом вложения одного рубля, поддерживая максимум
> лучшего вложения `Best` от начала до `k`-го элемента, и комбинируйте
> текущий максимум с `V[k+1]`, запоминайте лучшее значение `Best*V[k+1]`
>
> Алгоритм линейный

Для лучшего понимания я сделал массив `e` для прибылей по первой сделке (в реальности хранить его не требуется) и вывод массивов.

Доработку для получения самих дней сделок оставил вопрошающему.
Также следует обработать случай только одной сделки (это уже добавил)

```
pr = [int(i) for i in '2 1 4 3 2 3 8 6 1 3 6'.split()]
n = len(pr)
v = [0]*n
e = [0]*n
print(pr)

imax = n-1
bestdiff = 0
for k in reversed(range(n)):
    bestdiff = max(pr[imax] - pr[k], bestdiff)
    v[k] = bestdiff
    if pr[k] > pr[imax]:
        imax = k
print(v)

imin = 0
bestdiff = 0
maxprofit = 0
for k in range(n):
    bestdiff = max(pr[k] - pr[imin], bestdiff)
    e[k] = bestdiff
    if pr[k] < pr[imin]:
        imin = k
    if n - k > 2:
        profit = bestdiff * v[k+1]
        maxprofit = max(profit, maxprofit)

print(e)
print(max(maxprofit, max(e)))
```

Результат:

```
    b              s     b     s    дни сделок        
[2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 3, 8, 6, 1, 3, 6]   цены
[7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 0]   вторая купля-продажа
[0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 7, 7, 7, 0, 0]   первая купля-продажа
35                                  сумма у Кузи
```

Comment: Я хотел бы уточнить, что показывает нам переменная bestdiff? зачем нам записывать максимальную разницу? что она нам показывает?

Comment: У вас алгоритм не все учитывает: по заданию можно совершать не больше четырех сделок, чтобы достичь максимальной выгоды. Вы предлагаете совершить действия "Купить-продать" , соответственно, в виде пары  p[1] - p[6] и p[8] - p[10] с прибылью 35. Но тут можно сначала купить по цене p[1] и продать за p[2], потом купить 2 акции по цене p[4] и продать каждую по p[6], получив на руки 16 рублей, а потом купить 16 акций по p[8] и продать каждую по p[10]. Таким образом, на руках останется 96 рублей из 1 рубля, а количество сделок будет 3. С точки зрения вывода должно быть: 3 (сделки); 2 3; 5 7; 9 11

Comment: Вы неправильно интерпретировали условие - под четырьмя сделками имеется в виду **две покупки и две продажи** - в начале условия посмотрите.

Comment: bestdiff показывает, какую лучшую выгоду можно получить на участке от текущего дня до конца  - пояснение к V[k], куда она записывается (и аналогично от начала до текущего дня во втором цикле)

Comment: Хорошо, а почему именно надо смотреть на выгоду, соответственно, от текущего дня до конца и от начала до текущего дня? Не могу понять, зачем мы это делаем

Comment: Потому что это хорошо ;-) Задача в том, чтобы разделить весь промежуток на два интервала - для первой купли продаже, и после для второй. Простым перебором начал и концов это сделать можно, но будет очень долго (четвертая степень от длины массива). Если мы знаем, какой максимум цены есть после текущего дня, мы можем сразу понять, какая выгода будет, если купить сегодня. Таким образом, не нужно перебирать все дни для каждого текущего. Получается, что мы можем найти самые выгодные сделки, начинающиеся в текущий день, за **линейное время**, а не за **квадратичное**.

Comment: честно говоря, все равно непонятно... непонятно, в частности, и то, каким образом определять тогда дни транзакций

Comment: При выборе максимумов записывать, к чему они относятся.

Comment: @Mbo вот пример в котором ваше решение теряет смысл, хоть и верно считает сумму, которая не имеет смысла для данного решения: 2 2 2 1 2 9 2 9 10 2 2 2. b s b s дни сделок [2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 8, 2, 8, 9, 2, 2, 2] цены [8, 8, 8, 8, 7, 7, 7, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0] вторая купля-продажа [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 0, 0] первая купля-продажа 49 сумма у Кузи
Согласно Вашего результата, можно сделать вывод по первой купле-продаже, что лучше купить за 1, продать за 8 и это верно, но в моем же примере, оценка выдает по первой купле-продаже, что лучше купить за 1, а продать за 9, хотя в таком случае мы не сможем

Comment: Тогда и мой коммент надо скопировать: В данном случае одна сделка хуже, т.к. результат получается всего 8, а с двумя сделками - 49. А на случай одной - вы заметили в тексте `Также следует обработать случай только одной сделки? `

Answer (score 0):

```
n = int(input())
pr = list(map(int, input().split()))
v = [0]*n
e = [0]*n
sum_v_e = [0]*n
imax = n-1
bestdiff = 0

for k in reversed(range(n)):
    bestdiff = max(pr[imax] - pr[k], bestdiff)
    v[k] = bestdiff
    if pr[k] > pr[imax]:
        imax = k

imin = 0
bestdiff = 0

for k in range(n - 2):
    bestdiff = max(pr[k] - pr[imin], bestdiff)
    e[k] = bestdiff
    sum_v_e[k] = e[k] + v[k]

    if pr[k] < pr[imin]:
        imin = k

sum_all_element_v = sum(v)
sum_all_element_e = sum(e)


if sum_all_element_v == 0 and sum_all_element_e == 0:
    print(0)
elif sum_all_element_e == 0 or max(v) == max(sum_v_e):
    print(1)

    max_value = max(v)
    indices_max_v = [index for index, val in enumerate(v) if val == max_value]
    min_value = min(v)
    indices_min_v = v.index(min_value)
    print(indices_max_v[-1] + 1, indices_min_v + 1)
else:
    print(2)

    min_value = min(e)
    max_value = max(sum_v_e)
    indices_min_e = [index for index, val in enumerate(e[:sum_v_e.index(max_value) + 1]) if val == min_value]
    indices_max_e = sum_v_e.index(max_value) + 1
    print(indices_min_e[-1] + 1, indices_max_e)

    max_value = max(v[indices_max_e:])
    indices_max_v = [index for index, val in enumerate(v) if val == max_value]
    min_value = min(v)
    indices_min_v = v.index(min_value)
    print(indices_max_v[-1] + 1, indices_min_v + 1)

print(v)
print(e)
print(sum_v_e)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Подскажите, а чем необходимо дополнять? Что нужно еще добавлять к ответам?

Comment: Почему вы используете сумму, если нужно произведение?

Comment: @MBo для того, чтобы выходить на одну сделку и определять индекс максимальной продажи при двух сделках

Comment: @Mikle Для оценки одной сделки нужно второй мой цикл до конца довести (не до n-2), и взять из `e` максимум, и сравнить его с bestprofit.

Comment: @MBo но если мы до конца доведем, то выйдем за пределы списка и получим ошибку. Разве не так?

Comment: @Mikle Ну для двух крайних значений после `e[k] = bestdiff` не нужно ничего делать

Comment: @MBo если честно, немного запутался. Создал третий цикл до n и без значений после e[k] = bestdiff. В итоге у меня просто заполнился 'e' одинаковыми значениями и равен всегда bestdiff.

Comment: @Mikle Случай одной сделки же довольно элементарен `for k in range(n):
    bestdiff = max(pr[k] - pr[imin], bestdiff)  e[k] = bestdiff
    if pr[k] < pr[imin]:
        imin = k
    if n - k > 2:
        profit = bestdiff * v[k+1]
        maxprofit = max(profit, maxprofit)

print(e)

print(max(maxprofit, max(e)))`

Comment: @Mikle Нет. Все возможные объяснения я уже написал в своем ответе, про одну сделку добавил здесь, а с вашим решением зачем же мне разбираться? Оно разве выдаст ответ 35 для массива из моего примера?

Comment: @MBo в любом случае, спасибо за советы, попытаюсь сам.

Comment: @Mikle ВЫ попробуйте разобраться в моем ответе, задача с двумя сделками ведь довольно сложная.

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен на 100% но исправленное решение

```py
n = int(input())
pr = [int(x) for x in input().split(" ")]


r = [[0,[0,0]] for x in range(n)]
l = [[0,[0,0]] for x in range(n)]
print(pr)

imax = n-1
bestdiff = 0
best_b = n-1
best_s = n-1
for k in reversed(range(n)):
    if bestdiff < pr[imax] - pr[k]:
        bestdiff = pr[imax] - pr[k]
        best_b = k
        best_s = imax

    r[k][0] = bestdiff
    r[k][1]= [best_b, best_s]

    if pr[k] > pr[imax]:
        imax = k

print(r)

imin = 0
bestdiff = 0
best_b = 0
best_s = 0
for k in range(n):

    if bestdiff < pr[k] - pr[imin]:
        bestdiff = pr[k] - pr[imin]
        best_b = imin
        best_s = k

    l[k][0] = bestdiff
    l[k][1] = [best_b, best_s]

    if pr[k] < pr[imin]:
        imin = k

print(l)


r.sort(key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)
l.sort(key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)

max_profit = 0
deals = []

if len(l) >= len(r):
    base = l
    h = r
else:
    base = r
    h = l


for i in range(len(base)):
    for k in range(len(h)):

        if base[i][1][1] >= h[k][1][0] or base[i][1][0] >= h[k][1][1]:

            if max_profit < base[i][0] and base[i][0] >=  h[k][0]:
                max_profit = base[i][0] + 1
                deals = [base[i][1]]

            elif max_profit <  h[k][0] and  h[k][0] > base[i][0]:
                max_profit =  h[k][0] + 1
                deals = [h[k][1]]

        elif max_profit < base[i][0] *  h[k][0]:
            max_profit = base[i][0] *  h[k][0] + 1
            deals = [base[i][1],  h[k][1]]

print(len(deals))


for i in deals:
    print(f"{i[0]+1} {i[1]+1}")
```

Comment: Исправленное чьё решение? Почему у вас  `+ 1` в расчете прибыли (может, это ни на что не влияет)?

Comment: @MBo собственно ваше. Да это ни ничто не влияет это написал для соответствия с тем, сколько Кузя рублей "сделал" как в описании задачи. Исправил вывод для соответствия условию. Т.к. самому задача попалась, но не успел эту версию кинуть на проверку.

Comment: Ну как-то это переусложнено, да и сложность получается квадратичная, похоже.